# HTC One M8 running on Android Studio

Tags: android

Is anyone using a **HTC One M8** device on **Android Studio**? My problem is that the IDE is not recognising it.

I killed the AVD, restarted the IDE a few times, plugged-out and plugged-in the device, but It still being not recognised.

Comment: what OS are you using? If its windows, it could be a driver issue.

Comment: I am using Mac OS and the OS recognise the device.

Comment: Did you enable the debugging option in your phone settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirements to make the HTC One M8 to work with Android Studio are:

- Install HTC Sync Manager
- Enable the **USB debugging** made the **Android Studio** to recognise the device. [This](http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/unlock-hidden-developer-options-your-htc-one-m8-0154418/) article tells how to enable **Developer Option** in **Settings**, cause it comes hidden by default.

Comment: did you have to download an HTC specific driver? I allowed USB debugging on my phone but still nothing

Comment: Then when you connect the phone to the computer it will ask you to trust the computer, make sure you say yes. Then you should be able to see your device on Android Studio. You would not need any driver.

Comment: There should be a message on my phone along lines of "Trust this PC?"? I don't remember anything like that. Mostly stuff like "tap to stop USB debugging", "MTP media file transfer" or similar when I pulled down from top of screen. Would this "Trust this PC?" message also be seen by pulling down from top of phone's screen?

Comment: ah... and forgot to mention I'm on Windows PC

Comment: Probably you already agreed to trust you computer. You need to have the HTC Sync Manager installed and when your phone asks you about MTP media file transfer tap on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I needed to download the HTC Sync Manager onto my PC. Honestly it was hard to identify that as the fix, and a little difficult to find out how to download it. Would you mind updating your answer to include the fact that you installed `HTC Sync Manager`? That's a critical part that is not in your answer. The link to HTC Sync Manager, which I suggest you also include is: http://www.htc.com/us/software/htc-sync-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that worked for me, on **Windows 8.1**, using **HTC One M8**:

Follow [Android Studio's documentation here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html), for your relevant OS and phone.

If for some reason that link breaks, here's the steps:

1. Allow USB debugging on your phone, in the Developer Options (tap your software build number 7 times if you don't see Developer Options in phone's Settings)
2. Include this snippet in your `gradle.build`:

   `android {
       buildTypes {
           debug {
               debuggable true
           }
       ...
       }
   ...
   }`

For many, the above steps are all you need. But, on Windows, I still had issues with HTC driver.

To fix this you must install **HTC Sync Manager** onto your PC, which also installs the proper driver. [Link is here.](http://www.htc.com/us/software/htc-sync-manager/)

Comment: The Gradle configurations are not needed.