# Android Studio does not recognize HTC One M8 Dual Lense as a device

Tags: android, htc-android

Am having a similar problem as  [HTC One M8 running on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770081/htc-one-m8-running-on-android-studio) but with Windows 7 X64 Android Studio. Maybe someone can provide some hints:

Device: HTC M8 dual lens

Loaded and installed the new sdk: HTCDualLensSDK5

Platform:  Windows 7 x64

Android studio (0.6.0)

Updated android_winusb.inf to include

[Google.NTx86]

. 
.

;htc M8

%SingleAdbInterfacd%      = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0F63

%CompositeAdbInterface%   = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0F63&REV_0232

Enabled USB debugging on HTC M8

RESULT:do not see devices in android studio?

However, explorer shows file contents in M8

Note: running Nexus and Glass with no problem in this studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Install or update the HTS Sync Manager last version.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Installed latest HTS Sync Manager, but didn't seem to help Android Studio recognize the HTC.  Still open to suggestions.

Comment: Now try to update "Goolge USB Drivers" from SDK Manager->Extras->Google USB Drivers,

Comment: phone->setting->developer option->USB debugging mode enable it and try hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: onto the phone or onto the PC??

Comment: where / what do you download for "HTS Sync Manager" ?

Comment: They meant HTC Sync Manager, however, according to HTC's site, Effective 2020/09/27, HTC Sync Manager will no longer be available for download. Since I found this by searching on the PID and Vendor ID, if I locate a good replacement, I'll post it as an answer.